# Jquery, if optgroup does not contain

Tags: jquery, optgroup

I need help with the below jQuery, it's not working for me. I want to fire some actions only if `<optgroup label="Knowledge Base">` does not exist

My HTML (which can't be changed):

```
<select id="entry_forum_id" name="entry[forum_id]">
<optgroup label="Knowledge Base"> … </optgroup>
<optgroup label="Incidents"> … </optgroup>
<optgroup label="Articles"> … </optgroup>
</select>
```

My jQuery attempt:

```
if($('optgroup:not([label="Knowledge Base"])')) {
    alert('test');
}
```

Comment: FYI, your selector looks for any optgroup that _doesn't_ have `label="Knowledge Base"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('optgroup:not([label="Knowledge Base"])')` returns a jQuery wrapper object, you need to test its length property to check whether it contains any elements

You need to test

```
if($('optgroup[label="Knowledge Base"]').length == 0) {
    alert('test');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need the pseudo-selector :not.  Just check there are no optgroup with that label:

```
if($('optgroup[label="Knowledge Base"]').length == 0) {
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mx4DT/1/)